# Where is the iOS 15 `imageVariant` property?

Tags: ios, swift, image, ios15

Take a look at:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10251/?time=268

The speaker in this video shows us assigning into to `imageVariant` property.

I can't find that property. There is no UIView `imageVariant` in iOS 15, and I can't find an `imageVariant` property on any other class. But I could just be missing it. Can someone tell me where it is?

Comment: Maybe it's only for SwiftUI - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/symbolvariants

Comment: I thought of that but does the code in the video look like SwiftUI to you?

Comment: It is odd, but while the preceding code looks like UIKit, this particular snippet does look like SwiftUI.  The `.imageVariant` is a modifier applied to `actionsView` and it talks about the variant propagating down the view hierarchy. That isn't typically how you would describe UIKit behaviour.

Comment: There is also this comment on the session. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/688238. I think the api just didn't make it out of beta or changed or something.

Comment: @Paulw11 very nice find, thanks.